# How to color 2 circles intersection in different color in draw.io

Tags: draw.io

I am using draw.io. I have 2 circle that I would like to color. The first one is green, the 2nd is blue. That's all good.

[image]

But I want to color the intersection area to be red. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that software. However, you probably need to check to see if it has a boolean operation such as Divide. [See related answer here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/141218/affinity-designer-overlaying-colours/141228#141228)

Comment: https://drawio-app.com/create-venn-diagrams-with-draw-io/

Comment: It's Google's drawing tool. Http://draw.io

Answer (score 3):

1. In the shape library, under **basic** shape, select **pointed oval**.
2. Now make the Grids disable using shortcut `ctrl+Shift+G` OR using the menu option (View > grids ).
3. Now Draw two circles and adjust the **pointed oval** to cover the intersection area.
4. Right click on **pointed oval** shape, select option 'TO FRONT'. This will bring the **pointed oval** on top of other shapes.
5. color all three shapes with different colors of your choice.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in draw.io that would allow boolean operations. This would be the usual way to create such shapes using vector drawing software. However, I see you can import images, such as SVGs.

So, one possibility would be to make the shapes in some vector software such Inkscape which is free, and which does support boolean operations.

In Inkscape I selected, then duplicated the two circles, then used the "Intersect" boolean operation to create the intersected shape, set different fill colours, then saved the SVG.

Example showing the coloured shapes made in Inkscape

[image]

Finally I imported the SVG into draw.io

It seems to work quite well. The only downside is the SVG is not fully editable in draw.io - I can't see a way to split it apart or recolour the individual pieces. However it can be rescaled and since it's vector, the quality doesn't degrade.

[image]